# Error NU1202 when upgrading from Net 5.0 to Net 6.0

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-6.0

I am working on upgrading a project from NET 5.0 to NET 6.0 and it builds just fine in VS 2022 but I am trying to build it through command line using:

```
dotnet restore

dotnet publish /p:Configuration=Release
/p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile
```

and get the following errors:

```
error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web 6.0.3 is not compatible with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web 6.0.3 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 6.0.3 is not compatible with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 6.0.3 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
error NU1201: Project X is not compatible with net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0). Project X supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)
```

Here is the `.csproj` file for Project X:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Request\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And here is a screenshot showing NET 6.0 is installed on my server:
[NET 6.0 SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neynv.png)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue earlier (however from upgrading .net 6 to .net 7) and this and other answers i found online didn't fix the issue for me. Eventually i noticed that i hadn't also updated my publish profile file. Inside it was still staying:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

Once i updated that, it was working correctly again

Answer (score 0):

### Try these in order

### 1. Check you don't have a global.json pointing to the wrong SDK:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "5.0.0"
  }
}
```

### 2. Reinstall dotnet to make sure the latest SDK is definitely being picked up:

Sometimes the wrong SDK is picked up by default. You didn't say what platform, I'm assuming windows.

Try this:
You can use [WinGet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/), to install (or update) .NET:

#### Run from an admin command prompt

```
winget install Microsoft.dotnet
```

Comment: I have just again reinstalled NET 6.0 and am still receiving the same error. There is also no global.json file being used.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parameter

```
/p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile
```

Or change the 《TargetFramework》 in the

> Properties\PublishProfiles\FolderProfile.pubxml

content.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).